# Not able to import pynotify in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pynotify

i am using `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have a script which depends on `pynotify`. When the script is run outside any virtual environment then it runs fine (other dependencies also installed globally) but if i run the same script inside any virtual environment (other dependencies installed there as well), it doesn't work. 
Then i thought that i would have been installed it globally earlier but it was not. I tried this (globally):

```
pip freeze | grep pynotify
```

But, it didn't give any result. Is there any explanation to this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Update your virtualenv environment to include **system-site-packages**:

```
mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages your_virtual_env_name
```

> If you build with `virtualenv --system-site-packages ENV`, your
>   virtual environment will inherit packages from
>   `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (or wherever your global
>   site-packages directory is).
>
> This can be used if you have control over the global site-packages
>   directory, and you want to depend on the packages there. If you want
>   isolation from the global system, do not use this flag.

Source: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#the-system-site-packages-option

Comment: It works. But, doesn't it contradict the work virtualenv is supposed to do? It is using every thing that has been installed globally then what help does it do? I mean, without venv we can do the same, right? Normally, we  generate a `requirements.txt` file using `pip freeze`  and share the dependencies with others, but in this case it will contain many things which are not relevant to this project. Is there a way to include only the things which are relevant in requirements ?

Comment: __"Running virtualenv with the option --no-site-packages will not include the packages that are installed globally. This can be useful for keeping the package list clean in case it needs to be accessed later. This is the default behavior for virtualenv 1.7 and later."__ Source: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#other-notes

Comment: virtualenv by default will give you a clean environment with no packages installed and will not use your globally installed packages.  If you want pynotify in your project, the idea is to explicitly and separately install pynotify in that project under the clean environment using pip, not using the global packages already installed on the system.

Comment: Yeah, but i was talking about `--system-site-packages` .
I tried installing `pynotify` using `pip` but it fails. I tried your method, it worked, because it was able to check the globally installed packages. Also, my confusion after your answer was: when you create the virtualenv using the  `--system-site-packages`  and run `pip freeze` it gives the whole list with globally installed packages. Then if we try to pipeline to requirements.txt then it would include all the globally installed packages. I am not saying that it installs all the packages in the new venv.

Comment: I see.  I personally don't use `--system-site-packages` so I wouldn't know if it includes every package on the system or not in `pip freeze`, but I imagine it would.  Did you get any errors when you tried to run `pip install pynotify` inside of your virtual environment?

Comment: Downloading/unpacking pynotify
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pynotify
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pynotify
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmp4EOFVv

Comment: It doesn't look like the pynotify package **"notify-python"** is available from pypi.  I don't think you can install it using pip:  http://www.galago-project.org/files/releases/source/notify-python/notify-python-0.1.1.tar.gz  There is an alternative of notify-python called **notify2** on pypi that you can install with pip https://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2/